# MS Graph Valid User Attribute Reported as Request_ResourceNotFound

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-graph-api

The Graph API call with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX94105a4$select=mail` fails with

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX94105a4$select=mail' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",
```

But the call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX94105a4` **successfully** reports the user's "mail":

| Get User | Get User Mail |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Get User] | [image: Get User Email] |

Why & how to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you're using wrong url, you missed a question mark between Route and params. It should be

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX94105a4?$select=mail

Reference: [Use query parameters to customize responses - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters)

Comment: Cảm ơn! It's the small things that get ya. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `?` in the query before `$select`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX94105a4?$select=mail
```